# chrome.storage.local.set() is not working properly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm having a difficult time dealing with chrome storage. I've looked at the latest documentation for chrome storage and have the following code (this is a code snippet inside an ajax call success function, info.userName is a value returned by my backend program):

```
chrome.storage.local.set({ "userName": info.userName }, () => {
    chrome.storage.local.get("userName", function(data) {
        console.log(data.userName)
    });
});
```

but the console.log() always returns undefined, while I'm pretty sure that info.userName has a value. I've also tried this which is not working as well:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({ "userName": info.userName });
chrome.storage.local.get("userName", function(data) {
    console.log(data.userName)
});
```

It seems that the set function doesn't save anything locally, does anyone has any thought about this?

---

Finally figured it out, so my problem is that the value of info.userName is not JSON compatible. After I changed it the first code snippet above works well. Thanks for the comments below!

Comment: try `console.log(data)` - since you store a string, expect a string

Comment: The first code is correct, so it means that *at the time this code runs* your info.userName is either undefined or not JSON-compatible. Use devtools to set breakpoints and inspect what happens.

Comment: I've tried, and it returns {}. Nothing inside.

Answer (score -3):

you can do it by these way.....

- to set item in Local Storage
  **localStorage.setItem("message", "Hi, I am Local Storage...");**
- to get item value from Local Storage
  **localStorage.getItem("message");**
- to remove item from Local Storage
  **localStorage.removeItem("message");**

Comment: The [chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/) exists and it is not the same as localStorage, that you are referring to.